# how do I get an image to load in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do something relatively simple -- whenever a user clicks on a button in a form, an image is loaded and when it is done loading, it is displayed. While it is loading, there is a "loading" icon.

I tried the following Javascript code:

```
 <script>

 function loadImage()
 {
       myImage = new Image();

       myImage.onLoad = function()
      {
            document.img01 = myImage;
            alert("image loaded - debug msg");
      }

      myImage.src = "MyBigImage.cgi";

      document.img01.src = "loading.gif";
 }

 </script>

 <form method=get name=myForm id=myForm>

   <div id=img name=img>
   <img src=xx id=img01 name=img01>
   </div>

  <input type=button onClick='javascript:loadImage();'>
  </form>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I am not sure why, but even the alert is not displayed.
I tried to follow the instructions here:

http://fragged.org/preloading-images-using-javascript-the-right-way-and-without-frameworks_744.html

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to do this would be to inject the image later into the DOM once it has loaded. When the user clicks the button, we create the image and then add it into the DOM. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="show image" onClick='javascript:loadImage();' />
<div id="img" name="img"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function loadImage() {
    var myImage = document.createElement('img');

    myImage.onload = function() {
        alert("image loaded - debug msg");
    };

    myImage.src = "MyBigImage.cgi";

    document.getElementById('img').appendChild(myImage);
}
```

Finally, here's an example JSBin that shows you how it works: http://jsbin.com/nepijabe/1/edit?html,js,output